# unable to access the data of ngonchange to another methods without passing parameter in angularjs2

Tags: angular, typescript

app.component.html

```
<p> some code </p>
  <line-chart-demo [dataa]="graphScores"  ></line-chart-demo>
```

app.component.ts

```
graphScores:number[][];
this.graphScores = years;
```

line-chart.html
 https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

```html
<basechat with all options >
```

lineChartComponent.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e9UY.png)